# how to make some items of a listview non clickable?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have following code which is quite easy to understand. I want some specific child of this listview to be non clickable.

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.module_name_item, testdata);

    m_listview.setAdapter(adapter);


    Log.i("check","1");
    if(sectionAttempts.get(0).equals("0"))
    {

        m_listview.getChildAt(2).setEnabled(false);
        m_listview.getChildAt(3).setEnabled(false);
    }
    else
    {

        if(sectionAttempts.get(2).equals("0"))
        {

            m_listview.getChildAt(3).setEnabled(false);
        }


    }
```

I am getting error in

```
  m_listview.getChildAt(2).setEnabled(false);
```

as java.lang.NullpointerException. I tried to find the error and used Log.i("check",m_listview.getChildCount()); And it show 0. so i am guessing the listview hasnt beent created yet!! How is that possible.

What seems to be the problem? Thanx for any help in advance.

Comment: post what error are you getting

Comment: @slezadav : plzz see the updated question. I am guessing my listview isnt created before i call those statements??

Answer (score 16):

Override `areAllItemsSelectable()` method. Return false to say all the items are not clickable.

```
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsSelectable() {
    return false;
}
```

And then Override below method to return which item is not clickable

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if(position == your_item_pos) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This method prevented the separator lines from showing in between my list items. Instead, I set the following property in the XML of the ListView `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Sharing my experience, the following did the trick (view refers to the list item view):

```
view.setEnabled(false);
view.setOnClickListener(null);
```

- enabling by overriding the method didn't work as the method was never invoked.
- setting focusable to false didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if you didn't initilize your ListView.  In `onCreate`  Use `m_listview=getListView()` if you are using ListActivity or `m_listview=findViewById(R.id...)` if you are using regular activity.